# High wait time on pingdom tools

Tags: wordpress, pingdom

I have a wordpress site. When testing pages or posts they come back with a server wait time of 99% and load time of 20-20 seconds (amsterdam or stockhom server) For example this page: http://www.bredbaand-internet.dk/internetudbyder-med-hoej-upload-kviknet. It is not the host (3 different hosts tried). I have a similar problem for 3 other wordpress sites. (One with no plugins). They are all 3-4 year old installations.

Any good ideas?

Br

Andyboy

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be htaccess issues (Lines of codes blocking referral spam)